# I can't move pkg from Desk to stacks

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have download a package to the Desk,but i want move it to opt/ros/fuerte/stacks,"sudo mv"it doesn't work,could you tell me some useful methods?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61288/i-can%27t-move-pkg-from-desk-to-stacks/) by [tyl8891](https://answers.ros.org/users/4729/tyl8891/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't move any downloaded package to opt/ros/fuerte/stacks, make a folder and set it to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH, then move the downloaded package to that folder.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2013-04-23**:
There's also the workspace/rosws option... (that existed for rosbuild and is being pushed catkin) http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment#Create_a_ROS_Workspace